# C# Datetime cannot convert yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ to Datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, datetime-conversion

For a project I am creating an ASP.net Core Web API.

I created a POST endpoint for request from a Webhook (Java API)

My C# Class:

```
public class Data
{
    [JsonPropertyName("state")]
    public string? state { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("lat")]
    public double? lat { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("lng")] 
    public double? lng { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("accuracy")]
    public int? accuracy { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("source")]
    public string? source { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public int? id { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("time")]
    public DateTime? time { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("insertTime")]
    public DateTime? insertTime { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("serial")]
    public string? serial { get; set; }
}
```

So I thought datetime could dealing with following format: 2023-03-01T15:25:00+0000
But I always get an error from this type:

```
"The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]. Path: $.data.time | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 139."
```

Someone that have a solution?

Thanks in Advance.

UPDATE:

JSON :

```
{
   "dataType":"location",
   "data": {
       "state":"STOP",
       "lat":50.00,
       "lng":5.00,
       "source":"gps",
       "id":1804885154,
       "time":"2023-03-01T11:12:00+0000",
       "insertTime":"2023-03-01T11:18:30+0000",
       "serial":"xxxx"
    }
}
```

FULL C# CLASS:

```
public class SensolusSensorWebhook
{
    [JsonProperty("dataType")]
    public string? DataType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Data? Data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    [JsonPropertyName("state")]
    public string? state { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("lat")]
    public double? lat { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("lng")]
    public double? lng { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("accuracy")]
    public int? accuracy { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("source")]
    public string? source { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public int? id { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("time")]
    public DateTime? time { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("insertTime")]
    public DateTime? insertTime { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("serial")]
    public string? serial { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("thirdPartyId")]
    public string? thirdPartyId { get; set; }
}
```

Swagger UI Info:
[Foto van endpoint in swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlUpf.png)

Endpoint code:

```
[HttpPost("sensordata/sensolus")]  
public async Task<ActionResult> PostSensolusWebhook([FromBody] SensolusSensorWebhook? sensorWebhook)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Falls in PostSensolusWebhook");
    _logger.LogInformation($"Sensorwebhook: {sensorWebhook.ToString()}");
    await _sensorTestDataService.CreateAsync(sensorWebhook);

        
    return Ok(sensorWebhook);
}
```

Comment: Please include your JSON.

Comment: `2023-03-01T15:25:00+0000` isn't the same format as `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`.

Comment: In fact, `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` isn't a valid format. Did you mean `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffZ` instead?

Comment: So, `new DateTime(2023,3,1,15,25,2).AddMilliseconds(123).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffZ")` would give you `2023-03-01T15:25:02.123Z`. Does that help?

Comment: It might be problem with Microsoft JSON Date format, which looks more or less like:
/Date(1224043200000)/
I got that problem with nullable Datetime (Datetime?) in ASP .NET when i tried to display that date in Javascript components. It would be easier to guess, if you would give us that Json you are trying to deserialize.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama I updated the post with more information in it.

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik I updated the post with more information in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a converter for this case.

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("data.json");
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
var converter = new DateTimeConverterUsingDateTimeParse();

options.Converters.Add(converter);

var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Data>(json, options);
```

Here is the converter class

```
public class DateTimeConverterUsingDateTimeParse : JsonConverter<DateTime>
{
    public override DateTime Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        Debug.Assert(typeToConvert == typeof(DateTime));
        return DateTime.Parse(reader.GetString() ?? string.Empty, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
}
```

This code was taken from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/system-text-json-support?pivots=dotnet-7-0)

You can add your custom converter to your web server while configuring your services.

```
services.AddControllers()
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
             options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverterUsingDateTimeParse());
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, on my localhost it's working. Gonna try it now on the online service!
That last line is helpfull so i don't need to parse string to json. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks also working with the webhook!!!

Comment: You are parsing in the current culture, which will differ from machine to machine.  I'd suggest parsing in the invariant culture.  Or if the JSON appears to be from some specific culture, use that culture.

Comment: @dbc, I've edited my answer to parse the date with invariant culture, thx

Comment: I'd suggest also doing `writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))`.

Comment: @dbc done ! You might consider to tell Microsoft team as well :D